# Как открыть картинку с диска в с#(консольный проект)

Tags: c#, изображения

Сделано задание по графику. Требуется чтобы в начале проекта открывалась картинка(лучше в консоли), которая будет находиться на флешке.

[image: график]

```
using System;

namespace Задание_1
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Лаб. №3 Задание. №1.20. Тахаев Усам Руссланович");
            try {
                do {


                    Console.Write ("x=");
                    float x = float.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
                    Console.Write ("y=");
                    float y = float.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());

                    if (y == 23 || x == 0 || y==-x && x<0)
                        Console.WriteLine ("На границе");

                    else if (y < 23 && x < 0 && y - x > 0)
                        Console.WriteLine ("Внутри");

                    else
                        Console.WriteLine ("вне");
                    Console.Write("Для выхода нажмите Escape. Для продолжения любую другую клавищу\n");

                }
                while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "чтобы в начале проекта открывалась ..." - где находится "начало проекта"?

Comment: @Igor мне что-то подсказывает, что после `public static void Main` :)

Comment: хехехехе лабараторка )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Товарищи с SO [предлагают](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808029/open-image-in-windows-photo-viewer) пользоваться [Process-ом](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx):

```
Process photoViewer = new Process();
photoViewer.StartInfo.FileName = @"путь_к_программе_просмотра_изображений";
photoViewer.StartInfo.Arguments = @"путь_к_картинке";
photoViewer.Start();
```